# When a checkbox or button is clicked, how can I detect if a key is pressed?

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

For example is the user clicks a checkbox, how can I tell if the user was holding SHIFT, CTRL or any other key pressed ?

```
Checkbox(
    value: checked,
    onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
            // do something
        });
    },
),
```

Comment: Try ```RawKeyboardListener``` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RawKeyboardListener-class.html

Comment: Any example on how to do that ? I tried but didn't manage to find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In your `StateFull` `widget` do something like bellow snippet

```
bool _isChecked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Checkbox(
          value: _isChecked,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              _isChecked = value;
            });
          },
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Button'),
          onPressed: (){
            if(_isChecked){
              print('CHeckbox is checked');
            }else{
              print('CHeckbox is not checked');
            }
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: This can be done is stateless widget also, as we are not reflecting the changes in other widgets. it just assigning the values to global variable.

Comment: give an example then? I think as a beginner thats the right way.

Comment: You misunderstood the question. When the user clicks the checkbox, I want to know if the SHIFT key is pressed or not. Not if the checkbox is checked when the user presses another button.